# Daily outgoing traffic of ~10MB normal?

Tags: networking, shairplay

I recently installed RaspAP and through their interface I saw that in the past month, everyday I had outgoing traffic of ~8-12 MB on eth0.

Is it possible to see where this traffic went to?

I have only shairport-sync running, not much else, RaspAP is not active.

Comment: What is RaspAP and shairport-sync?

Comment: Also the answer is yes, but somehow I feel it won't satisfy you.